# Which boards with ARM(like stm32, etc.) can have GPIO pins which can give 3.8V or higher as an output?

Tags: microcontroller, arm, stm32, microprocessor

I am trying to get pulses from my board. Right now, I am using stm32f103 board. 
The problem is that output voltage values of pulses are 3.3V but I need at least 3.8V or higher.
As I understand ,I cannot have it with my stm32f103 board. So I am looking for the ARM-based boards whose GPIO pins can give 3.8V or higher voltage values as an output.
Thanks...

Comment: You could put an amplifier/buffer between the GPIO and the destination. A simple HCT gate would do.

Comment: The Kinetics/NXP KE0 can operate at 5V.

Comment: he wants to output 5v , not only survive at 5v input , which is think is not available , unless buffers or transistors etc... is used

Comment: @ElectronS the KE0 family are true 5V parts and can output 5V.

Comment: This is currently a shopping question therefore it should be closed. I suggest to rephrase it and ask about how can you create 5 V or at least 3.8 V pulses with an STM32F103.

Comment: @steve G , he tricked me by saying "The Kinetics/NXP KE0 can survive at 5V" , before he edited the comment as far as i remember , so i thought that means that pins are 5v tolerant which is quite common . otherwise i think i am still under the effects of alcohol (99% electronics grade) :) :p

Comment: Many ST's have 5v tolerant pins, which you can bring to 5v using open gate output configurations and pulling them high to 5v.  The board you have can probably do this.

Answer (score 3):

How fast do you need the pulses?

There are very few 5V ARM cpus (e.g. The NXP KE series parts @Wouter van Ooijen mentioned). And the dev board for those parts [here](http://www.nxp.com/products/software-and-tools/hardware-development-tools/freedom-development-boards/kinetis-e-series-freedom-development-platform:FRDM-KE02Z) runs the CPU at 3.3V not 5V.

There may be an arm dev board out there with 5V IO but if there is one you're not going to have much choice on part.

However there are lots of 5V tolerant parts available on boards, if you configure the IO pins as open drain (high impedance for a high output) and connect a pull up resistor to 5V then you can get a 5V output from the part.
The down side in this is that the rising edges aren't particularly sharp, for high speed signals or something with very critical edge timing this may be an issue.

If you need a sharp edge then a 3V3 part and a buffer to drive the line is probably your best option.

Comment: The SAM Cs are 5V capable (not just 5V tolerant) as well, BTW